# The Stack Overflow mobile version is very ugly on a Kindle3

Tags: support, kindle

The mobile version looks ugly, half of the entries have a black background (don't know why, seems random) which makes them so hard to read.

Is there any way to work around it?

Comment: No way to get a screenshot, is there?

Comment: Change your user agent?

Comment: @John: You can't change your user agent on a Kindle.

Comment: Petition Amazon to stop including half-baked rendering engines in its products that it disingenuously calls web browsers?

Comment: I would bet that these are the highlighted interesting questions, and since Kindle does only two colors (i.e. black and white), it can't do a nice highlight and did its best with what it could.

Answer (score 8):

You can take screenshots with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, a GIF will show up in your `documents` folder.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I've also tried browsing Stack Overflow from the Kindle before. The non-mobile version is too heavy to use nicely. It's also a chore to reach the link you want using the four-way navigation thing, when the page is loaded with links. The mobile version would probably be adequate if it weren't for this.

I don't browse much of a variety of sites from the Kindle, but I can't remember seeing this bug before.

Comment: As a developer, can't you now try and fix this blackness? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard All of my Kindle 3s have broken in the five year since I made this post. I didn't think new Kindles even had the web browser, but apparently I'm wrong. If I ever get my hands on one I'll take a look. :P